# Lexicographic Permutations

Tags: scala, functional-programming, permutation

I have been working on the Project Euler [problem 24](http://projecteuler.net/problem=24) and came across a solution in *Scala* (the language I was trying to solve it in anyway). I had intended to do it myself, but am now transfixed on finding out how this solution works.

The problem:

> The lexicographic permutations of 0, 1 and 2 are:
>
> 012, 021, 102, 120, 201, and 210.
>
> What is the millionth lexicographic permutation of the 
>   digits 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9?

The solution:

```
def permutations(s : String) : Seq[String] =
{
  if(s.size == 1)
    Seq(s);
  else
    s.flatMap(x => permutations(s.filterNot(_ == x)).map(x +));
}

val ans = permutations("0123456789")(1000000 - 1).toLong;

println(ans);
```

Comment: A more interesting question is what the trillionth element is (let's say of a larger alphabet), since it forces you to actually figure out the patterns.

Comment: That code might be a lot clearer as a for comprehension, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is trivial in Scala:

```
"0123456789".permutations.drop(999999).next
```

Comment: Nice succinct solution ;)

Answer (score 3):

It might be instructive to look at the following functional implementation (although it does not produce permutations in lexicographic order).

I will use `List`s in the following instead of `String`s, since they are ubiquitous in functional programming and facilitate to think of "recursive solutions". A list is either empty `Nil` or consists of a first element (the head of the list) and the remaining list (the tail of the list) `x :: xs`.

Now a typical "functional" way of cooking up a solution for a problem involving lists, is to think how a solution for a non-empty list `x::xs` may be obtained from a solution for `xs`.

In the case of permutations, the problem is

> Assuming we have all permutations of the list `xs`, how do we obtain all permutations of `x::xs`?

**Example:** Assume we have all permutations of `List(1, 2)`, i.e.,

```
List(1, 2)
List(2, 1)
```

how do we obtain all permutations of `List(0, 1, 2)`, which are

```
List(0, 1, 2)
List(1, 0, 2)
List(1, 2, 0)
List(0, 2, 1)
List(2, 0, 1)
List(2, 1, 0)
```

A close look reveals that we just inserted `0` in all possible ways into solutions for `List(1, 2)`.

Thus if we have a function that produces all possible results of inserting a single element into a given list -- lets call it `inserts` -- then a solution might look as follows

```
def permutations[A](xs: List[A]) : List[List[A]] = xs match { 
  case Nil => List(Nil)
  case x::xs => permutations(xs).flatMap(inserts(x, _))
}
```

That is, if the given list `xs` is empty, there is only one permutation, namely the empty list. Otherwise, we first compute all permutations of `xs` (via the recursive call) and then insert `x` in all possible ways into the thus obtained lists.

A function to generate all possible insertions of `x` into the list `ys` could look as follows:

```
def inserts[A](x: A, ys: List[A]) : List[List[A]] = ys match {
  case Nil => List(List(x))
  case y::ys => (x::y::ys) :: inserts(x, ys).map(y::_)
}
```

If `ys` is empty then the result is just the singleton list `List(x)`. Otherwise, we again "think recursively", i.e., assume we have all possible insertions of `x` into `ys`, how do we obtain all possible insertions of `x` into `y::ys`? First we add `y` in front of all solutions for `ys` -- `inserts(x, ys).map(y::_)` -- yielding all solutions that do start with `y`; then we add the solution where `x` is the first element, namely `x::y::ys`.

**Note:** Of course this solution differs in the order of results from what is required in Project Euler. That's the reason why the solution in the initial post "mixes" the two steps of computing permutations for a smaller list and then using them to generate permutations of the full list. Here the smaller "list" is `s.filterNot(_ == x)` (which is at least one element shorter than `s`, since `x` is an element of `s`) which is used in the recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an imperative equivalent pseudo-code to explain the solution you gave:

```
foreach (x: s) { // flatMap in the code
  val lst = permutations(all character of s except x) // permutations(s.filterNot(_ == x)) in the code
  foreach (permutation: lst) { // map in the code
    append(x, permutation) // (x +) in the code
    // example: x = "0" and permutation = "21" yield "021"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This all boils down to how you classify the permutations of `s`:

You can group the permutations by their first character. Since the first character is fixed within such a group, that group is basically: the first character + the permutations of all others. That is the induction step of the algorithm. The base step is just that there is only one permutation of a single element.

If you look at the Scala code:

```
// this is the base step
if(s.size == 1)
  Seq(s)
```

And the recursion step reads:

- for each character `x` in `s`,

  - compute `permutations` of all the others,
  - re-add `x` at the beginning of all of them,
  - and you get all the permutations starting with `x`.
- concatenate (flatten) all those groups together.

Hence:

```
s.flatMap(x => permutations(s.filterNot(_ == x)).map(x + _))
```

Comment: This has helped me understand what the code is doing, although i don't think i can code thinking this way just yet...soon though :)